# javascript удаление всех слушателей

Tags: javascript, html

Есть 2е главные функции в JS, постоянное отслеживаю ширину экрана, и при изменении до нужных пределов, использую нужную мне функцию, да только обработчики ранее запускаемой функции остаются и никуда не деваются, хотя мне их не надо, только мешают, как их удалить?

```
var init = function () {

        if ($(window).width() < minWindowWidth) {
            runOnMobileInit();
        } else {
            runOnWebInit();
        }
    };

    init();
    $(window).resize(init);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Универсально удалить все слушатели с элемента: `$(window).off();`

Но, имейте в виду, это немного опасная практика. Самое лучше что можно придумать, это использовать события со своим неймспейсом и удалять только их. Мало ли, какой другой элемент слушает тоже самое событие на том же самом элементе. Вот такой пример:

```
// в одном месте первый элемент слушает resize
$(window).on('resize.first_event', function () {...});

// в другом месте другой элемент тоже слушает:
$(window).on('resize.second_event', function () {...});

// если мы сейчас используем $(window).off();
// то мы нечаянно обрубим и первый слушатель,
// по этому идеально использовать namespaced events

$(window).off('resize.second_event');
// и всё, второй слушатель снят, первый остался цел
```